# CSS Selector based on font-weight?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to create a selector that would identify elements with specific HTML font-weight properties?

Something like (***fake*** example):

```
div[font-weight^='900']{
    font-family:"HaasGrotDisp55Roman";
}
div[font-weight^='500']{
    font-family:"HaasGrotDisp35Thin";
}
```

w/ font-face css definitions as:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'HaasGrotDisp35Thin';
    src: url('fonts/neuehaasgrotdisp-35thin.eot');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'HaasGrotDisp55Roman';
    src: url('fonts/neuehaasgrotdisp-55roman.eot');
}
```

Comment: Not without JavaScript, no.

Comment: How would it be done with JavaScript?

Comment: Expensively, almost certainly slowly and with loops. And lots of calls to (in non-IE browsers) `window.getComputedStyle()`.

Comment: HTML does not have a `font-weight` property, so no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
/* Your fonts */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'HaasGrotDisp';
    src: url('fonts/neuehaasgrotdisp-35thin.eot');
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'HaasGrotDisp';
    src: url('fonts/neuehaasgrotdisp-55roman.eot');
    font-weight: 900;
    font-style: normal;
}

body { font-family: "HaasGrotDisp" }

h1,h2,h3 { font-weight: 900 }
```

This minifies it to only one font-family. Simply assign the different weights inside your @font-faces

And as for your attribute like query: I would suggest using semantic classes to use it with divs.

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely helpful.
_Some background on why I am asking:_ Trial-ing Adobe edge Reflow which limits font-face application to some standard web fonts (Arial, Verdana, etc..) or their proprietary typekit based library. Neither of these is able to use my desired .OTF font, neuehaasgrotdisp... So, in Reflow I am tagging text elements with different weights and post-processing the generated html/css manually.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Add classes to elements so that you can apply certain font-weight's to those elements. Use those same classes for to "identify" elements that have a certain font-weight. That's how CSS works.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, css selector will work on element name or attributes, but not css. besides, even if it were possible, it would be strongly discouraged to do so. instead you can define class for each font face, and apply class to approriate div's, and search div's with those classes.

eg)

```
`
    .Haas {
      font-family: '...';
    }
    .Neue {
      font-family: '...';
    }

    ...
    <div class="some_class Haas">....
`
```